# Is there any alternative for ktgpio to access GPIOs on a Raspberry Pi using Kotlin Native?

Tags: kotlin, raspberry-pi, kotlin-native, ktgpio

I'm happy that I found the [ktgpio](https://github.com/ktgpio/ktgpio) library to access GPIOs, I2C, etc on a Raspberry Pi.

It seems that the project has dried up and yes it works great, it would be awesome to have a community or at least a documentation in more depth maybe to the fact that I'm a beginner in accessing sensors, etc.

In my case I successfully controlled a Blinkt! HAT and now I try to get sensor information from a BMP-280. The temperature is working but the pressure isn't.

I checked Pi4J and others but all of them are JVM based and not compatible using Kotlin Native.

Has anyone of you an idea what alternative I could pick?